# SQLAlchemy. Я пытаюсь получить объект, который записал в бд, но почему-то получаю пустой список

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

```
async def insert_order(item: CreateOrderDto, session: AsyncSession):
    query = insert(order).values(**item.get_order())
    result = await session.execute(query)
    return result.all()
```

Я пишу простое приложение на python, использую framework FastAPI. Моя цель: записать переданный объект в бд и вернуть этот объект обратно; но я не могу получить его id, т.к. получаю пустой список.

Comment: А `insert` точно должен возвращать `id`?

Comment: query это запрос, а session.execute() должен вернуть вставленную запись

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо тебе:) твой вопрос меня побудил кое-что проверить и в итоге проблема была в запросе :) Вот такой запрос должен быть query = insert(order).values(**item.get_order()).returning(order.c.id)

Comment: Добавьте прямо ответ с этим кодом, может кому ещё поможет )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо было к query добавить функцию returning(). В итоге решение выглядит так:

```
async def insert_order(item: CreateOrderDto, session: AsyncSession):
    query=insert(order).values(**item.get_order()).returning(literal_column('*'))
    result = await session.execute(query)
    return result.one()
```